# Passwordless ssh to sudo account

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sudo

If I have got a user access to UNIX box using passwordless ssh and now if I want to do say

```
sudo su - hdfs
```

Moreover, the sudo access exits in the sudoers file, but it's asking for my password. Definitely I don't know because I logged in passwordless mode.

**Question:** How to fix the same so that it takes credentials automatically, as it did for login into the account.

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour) is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

Comment: Nothing to do with `ssh`. When sudoing you are always asked to prove that you are the sudoer user and this is done by asking your password, even if you provided it already. This is a minimal security measure to prevent somebody that would get a temporary access to your terminal from accessing superuser privileges. If you need another behaviour have a look at the `sudo` documentation, understand the security consequences of your choices and customize the `/etc/sudoers` configuration file.

Comment: The short answer is to add yourself to the `wheel` group and then edit your *sudoers* file (as *root*) with `visudo` and uncomment the `%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` line. Now all members of *wheel* will have full `sudo` access to all files/applications without a password. You can do the same thing for `su` in `/etc/pam.d/su` and uncomment `auth            sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid` and `auth            required        pam_wheel.so use_uid` (not all distros provide the options commented, so you may have to add).

Answer (score 2):

Your passwordless access is because you're using a key, most likely RSA or DSA which does not have a password. That's for SSH athentication though, it has no use in its current capacity once you're in the system.

To not have to enter a sudo password for your user, you'll need someone with perms to add this to the sudoers file. Currently your user will be allowed to use sudo.

```
visudo
```

To edit /etc/sudoers. To have it so you never need to use a password for sudo you could do something like:

```
ramish ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

*ramish being your user, or for specific commands or binaries if it's just hdfs you need:

```
ramish = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/hdfs
```

Again, whatever your user is and whatever the commands are.